# SSIS 2008 package restore?

Tags: ssis, package

I'm working on a package in SSIS 2008 but I made a mistake and saved it.
How can I go back to the previous version of my package?

Answer (score 1):

You retreive it from source control like any other code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed the previous version to SQL Server, you can reverse the process to get back to your original package.

If you have not deployed the previous version and you dont have source control, then you have lost the ability to go back.